# Enabling floating point exceptions on MinGW GCC?

Tags: gcc, signals, mingw-w64, floating-point-exceptions

How does one enable floating point exceptions on [MinGW GCC](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv), where [feenableexcept](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Control-Functions.html) is missing? Even [reasonably complete solutions](https://gist.github.com/jvranish/4441299) don't actually catch this, though it would appear that they intend to. I would prefer minimal code that is close to whatever future standards will emerge. Preferably, the code should work with and without SSE. A complete solution that shows how to enable the hardware signal, catch it, and reset it is preferable. Compiling cleanly with high optimization levels and full pedantic errors and warnings is a must. The ability to catch multiple times in a unit-test scenario is important. There are several questions that [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247053/) [partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941611/) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860999/).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work on my machine. Compile it in MinGW GCC with `-fnon-call-exceptions`. It isn't fully minimized yet.

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cfloat> //or #include <float.h> // defines _controlfp_s
#include <cmath>
#include <csignal>

#ifdef _WIN32
void feenableexcept(uint16_t fpflags){
 /*edit 2015-12-17, my attempt at ASM code was giving me
  *problems in more complicated scenarios, so I
  *switched to using _controlfp_s. I finally posted it here
  *because of the upvote to the ASM version.*/
 /*{// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247053/
  uint16_t mask(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~fpflags);
  asm("fldcw %0" : : "m" (mask) : "cc");
 } //https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html   */
 unsigned int new_word(0);
 if (fpflags & FE_INVALID) new_word |= _EM_INVALID;
 if (fpflags & FE_DIVBYZERO) new_word |= _EM_ZERODIVIDE;
 if (fpflags & FE_OVERFLOW) new_word |= _EM_OVERFLOW;
 unsigned int cw(0);
 _controlfp_s(&cw,~new_word,_MCW_EM);
}
#endif

void fe_reset_traps(){
 std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT); //clear x87 FE state
#ifdef __SSE__
 _MM_SET_EXCEPTION_STATE(0); // clear SSE FE state
#endif
 feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO|FE_OVERFLOW|FE_INVALID); // set x87 FE mask
#ifdef __SSE__
 //set SSE FE mask (orientation of this command is different than the above)
 _MM_SET_EXCEPTION_MASK(_MM_MASK_DENORM |_MM_MASK_UNDERFLOW|_MM_MASK_INEXACT);
#endif
}

void sigfpe_handler(int sig){
 std::signal(sig,SIG_DFL); // block signal, if needed
 std::cerr<<"A floating point exception was encountered. Exiting.\n";
 fe_reset_traps(); // in testing mode the throw may not exit, so reset traps
 std::signal(sig,&sigfpe_handler); // reinstall handler
 throw std::exception();
}

fe_reset_traps();
std::signal(SIGFPE,&sigfpe_handler); // install handler
std::cerr<<"before\n";
std::cerr<<1.0/0.0<<"\n";
std::cerr<<"should be unreachable\n";
```

I'm sure it's not perfect. Let's hear what everyone else has to contribute.